# Where to ask Question that can be flagged too broad or opinion based

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I came across the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124609/frontend-backend-for-a-social-networking-mobile-web-app

This can be easily flagged for **too broad** or **opinion based,** but I wonder on which stack-exchange site can one ask answers for such a question?

Comment: All of the sites in the SE network share a common theme: they are focused on questions and answers rather than forum-like discussions. Requests for opinions and discussions are off-topic for all SE sites (with the exception of the meta sites where discussion is limited to topics relating to the main sites).

Comment: [Why can't we ask for opinions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112075)

Comment: Thanks for linking to a question that should be closed as opinion based though.

Comment: Find a forum site that welcomes broad, opinion-based questions and debates.

Comment: That's like asking where you can go to shoplift and get caught.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That's a poor analogy.  In the OP's case, every site other than the SE network loves such questions.  I don't know of lots of stores that don't mind shoplifters, anywhere.

Comment: Downvotes for a discussion :O ?? I know that SE is not for such questions, but was asking where can users be guided to coz I see a lot of opinion based questions being asked

Comment: Your premises are off – Stack Exchange sites are not forums and will never host opinion based discussions.

Comment: @Ani [Downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) (and not just on posts tagged [tag:feature-request] -- in this case I think the downvotes are basically saying "This isn't what SE is for, and we don't think changing that is a good idea.")

Comment: @voretaq7 thnx for explaining, sounds fair!

Answer (score 3):

The [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com) for an appropriate SE site is your best bet.

That only works if the question is a good one, and there are rational opinions though. Walking into SO chat and asking "Which is better, C++ or Java?" will just get you lynched by Python and Ruby people.

Comment: And the effect it will have on C++ programmers can seem quite similar to a lynching.

Comment: Death by snark... not a pretty sight.